# C# AesGcm and large files

Tags: c#, .net, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement encryption for files using the AesGcm class and
I found this question [Using the AesGcm class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889345/using-the-aesgcm-class) and while able to successfully encrypt / decrypt files the issue with this solution is that I need to load everything into memory.

So the question is, how can I use this AesGcm for large files without loading it all into memory? If I look at [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/src/System/Security/Cryptography/AesGcm.OpenSsl.cs#L57C42-L57C42) it always calls finalize so I cannot call the method multiple times and then in the end calculate the tag. To me, it seems like the only way would be to read a chunk of the file and then call encrypt and repeat it until the whole file is encrypted, however that feels like a hack and you would be able to reorder the different chunks.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with C# but the libraries from Bouncy Castle (Java and C#) are very equal and they do have "update" methods for chunking and a "finalize" call for final "cleanup".

Comment: I have looked at bouncy castle but their documentation is less then optimal so I would prefer to use the dotnet provided class instead if possible

Comment: The answer is streaming. But that would allow access to the data before tag verification which is not secure. I think the easiest method would be to treat your large files as chunks of data to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: Decryption should only take place after successful authentication. However, to determine whether authentication is successful, the entire ciphertext is required. For this reason, most GCM implementations process the data all at once and are therefore not suitable for (very) large data. However, solutions for the latter are conceivable (splitting the plaintext in segments, s. also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/81539)), but are not implemented in this way by most libraries.